# Unable to start Apache2: Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: php, apache2, freepbx

See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@ip-172-31-43-5:/home/ubuntu/asterisk-18.13.0/freepbx# systemctl status apache2.service

● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-07-27 08:30:40 UTC; 8s ago
Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
Process: 11172 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 27 08:30:40 ip-172-31-43-5 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jul 27 08:30:40 ip-172-31-43-5 apachectl[11175]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Jul 27 08:30:40 ip-172-31-43-5 apachectl[11175]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Jul 27 08:30:40 ip-172-31-43-5 apachectl[11175]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Jul 27 08:30:40 ip-172-31-43-5 apachectl[11175]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jul 27 08:30:40 ip-172-31-43-5 apachectl[11172]: Action 'start' failed.
Jul 27 08:30:40 ip-172-31-43-5 apachectl[11172]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jul 27 08:30:40 ip-172-31-43-5 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 27 08:30:40 ip-172-31-43-5 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 27 08:30:40 ip-172-31-43-5 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

Answer (score -1):

uninstall apache  and reinstall again

sudo apt-get install apache2
install Apache2

sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_ajp proxy_balancer proxy_connect proxy_ftp proxy_http

Comment: I did it more than twice but issue still persists.

Comment: Try "sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN" and search what is using port 80

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).